# Realizar ação após usuário parar de digitar com Jquery

Tags: jquery

Estou fazendo um Suggest de pesquisa onde depois que o usuário digitar pelo menos 4 letras no input ele faz via Ajax a busca com as sugestões para o usuário. Mas atualmente depois que o usuário digitou as 4 primeiras letras da palavra é feita uma nova requisição Ajax a cada letra digitada e eu gostaria que as requisições Ajax fossem realizadas somente depois que o usuário parasse de digitar no input. Segue o fonte:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     (function(){
          'use strict';

          $('#search').keyup(function(){
               var $this = $(this);
               var valueSeach = $this.val()

               if(valueSeach.length >= 4){
                   $.ajax({
                      url: "consulta.php",
                      dataType: "json",
                      data: {
                          acao: 'autocomplete',
                          parametro: valueSeach
                      },
                      success: function(data) {
                          response(data);
                      }
                  });
               }                                                        
          });
      })();
  </script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

É bem complicado identificar quando o usuário parou de digitar, o que você pode fazer é colocar um intervalo para realizar a pesquisa da sua sugestão.

Um exemplo disto seria contando 1 segundos após o evento `keyUp` então se ele ficou 1 segundos sem digitar um novo caractere você pode realizar a requisição e pegar as sugestões.

### Exemplo:

```js
var typingTimer; //timer identifier
var doneTypingInterval = 1000; //time in ms, 1 second for example

//on keyup, start the countdown
$('#myInput').keyup(function() {
  clearTimeout(typingTimer);
  if ($('#myInput').val) {
    typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
  }
});

//user is "finished typing," do something
function doneTyping() {
  console.log('parei de digitar');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myInput">
```

Mais detalhes: [Run Javascript Function when User Finishes typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220126/run-javascript-function-when-user-finishes-typing-instead-of-on-key-up)